# .aspx url with query string is unable to redirect to url without .aspx - Also i want to retain the query string on new url

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis, web-config

I have to redirect multiple URL's to new URL. Old URL was with extension (.aspx) I have redirected all old url to the new one using IIS and it is working fine. But when some query string is added to the old url it does not redirect to the new URL.

For Example redirection works perfectly for this: 
/course-guide.aspx to /course-guide

But when query string is added (/course-guide.aspx?UTM=campain) it goes to 404 page not found. But it should go to /course-guide?UTM=campain

Here in query string it can be anything. So i have to write a rule in web.config in such that it should work for all.

```
<rewrite>
   <rules> 
     <rule name="Redirect old url to Newb">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{Newb:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"  />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false"  />
     </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
     <rewriteMap name="Newb">
         <add key="/about-us.aspx" value="/about-us" />
         <add key="/course-guide.aspx" value="/course-guide" />
         </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```

I am expecting that 
/course-guide.aspx?UTM=camp to redirect to /course-guide?UTM=camp 
and in query string it can be anything.

Comment: What happens if you set **appendQueryString** to true?

Comment: Even if i set **appendQueryString** to true it goes to 404 page not found.

Comment: Can it be an error in your rewrite rules, that they can not handle query parameters.

Comment: I update the rule suggested by @emmguyot but still it did not worked.

Comment: Does it work if you manually enter */course-guide?UTM=camp* in the browser?

Comment: Yes if i manually enter /course-guide?UTM=camp in the browser it opens. But if .aspx is added then does not redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule are using an exact match for {REQUEST_URI} and this variable also contain query string. So try to replace {REQUEST_URI} to{URL}.

```
<rules>
                <rule name="Redirect old url to Newb" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{Newb:{URL}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Temporary" />
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module you should name the rewriteMap in your condition, like this :

`<add input="{Newb:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"  />`

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you add a rule that rewrites from non .aspx to aspx?

```xml
<rewrite>
   <rules> 
     <rule name="Redirect old url to Newb">
        <match url=".*" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{Newb:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)"  />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true"  />
     </rule>
     <rule name="Rewriter" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^([^/]+)?$"/>
        <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
  <rewriteMaps>
     <rewriteMap name="Newb">
         <add key="/about-us.aspx" value="/about-us" />
         <add key="/course-guide.aspx" value="/course-guide" />
         </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
</rewrite>
```